# Are there any references on extensions $G$ of a cyclic group $C_2$ by $2$-groups $P$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, p-groups, group-extensions

Are there any references on extensions $G$ of a cyclic group $C_2$ by $2$-groups $P$ such that $1\neq a\in C_2$ is a square element in $G$?

In other words, if $G/{C_2}\cong P$, where $P$ is a 2-group, and $1\neq a\in C_2$ is a square element in $G$, then what can we see on the structure of $G$? Are there any references on these group extensions?

Comment: You can take any 2-group $Q$ and take its central product with $C_4$, identifying the order 2 subgroup with some central element in $Q$.

Comment: In other words,  $G$ is a $2$-group in which some element in the centre is also a square. The vast majority of $2$-groups satisfy that condition. The question is far too broad.

Comment: @Derek Holt, thank you! uh, what I mean is $G/K\cong P$, $P$ is a 2-group, $K\cong C_2$, and $1\neq a\in K$ is a square.

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean. My previous comment still applies.

Comment: Numerical evidence that supports the above comments: out of 267 non-isomorphic 2-groups of order 64, 266 groups satisfy the condition. ($G = \mathsf{SmallGroup}(64, 267) \cong C_2^6$ is the only non-example.) So I would say more than 99% of 2-groups satisfy the condition. In other words, it is almost equivalent to the classification of finite 2-groups.

Comment: Thank you very much!